# What are the different materials for ski climbing skins and advantages to each?

Tags: skiing, gear, backcountry

I'm using mohair climbing skins right now but I've heard of other materials. What others are there and how do they compare to mohair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mohair is lighter and glides better than nylon, but does not grip the snow as well going uphill as nylon does.

I have used rubber skins before, which will really climb steep stuff, won't glide very well at all, and weigh a ton.